# Creating terrain mesh from script using perlin noise

Tags: c#, generator, mesh, noise

how I can add octaves to my perlin noise? I tried some ways, but it not work, for ex. adding multiple noises or changing noise variables in for loop like for( int o = 0; o < octaves; o++) in other for loop(in loop for zSize and xSize) but it not work... then I tried it by adding private float CalculateNoise(float x, float z){float noise; noise = Mathf.PerlinNoise(x * multiplier,z * multiplier) * 5; noise += ...; noise -=...; return noise;} <- but it would return only first row of noise...and that's only creating of perlin noise, not edits... :/

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MeshGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{

Mesh mesh;

Vector3[] vertices;
int[] triangles;
Vector2[] uvs;

public int xSize;
public int zSize;
public int seed;
[Header("Noise")]
float height;
public float multiplier = .3f;
public float scale = 1;
public int octaves = 8;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    mesh = new Mesh();
    GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;

    CreateMesh();
    UpdateMesh();
}
void CreateMesh()
{
    vertices = new Vector3[(xSize + 1) * (zSize + 1)];

    for (int i = 0, z = 0; z <= zSize; z++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x <= xSize; x++)
        {
            height = Mathf.PerlinNoise(x * multiplier, z * multiplier) * 2;
            vertices[i] = new Vector3(x, height, z);
            i++;
        }
    }

    triangles = new int[xSize * zSize * 6];

    int vert = 0;
    int tris = 0;

    for (int z = 0; z < zSize; z++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < xSize; x++)
        {
            triangles[tris + 0] = vert + 0;
            triangles[tris + 1] = vert + xSize + 1;
            triangles[tris + 2] = vert + 1;

            triangles[tris + 3] = vert + 1;
            triangles[tris + 4] = vert + xSize + 1;
            triangles[tris + 5] = vert + xSize + 2;

            vert++;
            tris += 6;
        }
        vert++;
    }

    uvs = new Vector2[vertices.Length];
    for (int i = 0, z = 0; z <= zSize; z++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x <= xSize; x++, i++)
        {
            uvs[i] = new Vector2((float)x / xSize, (float)z / zSize);
        }
    }

}

void UpdateMesh()
{
    mesh.Clear();

    mesh.vertices = vertices;
    mesh.triangles = triangles;
    mesh.uv = uvs;

    mesh.RecalculateNormals();
}

}
```